# How to access parents in recursive directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, recursion, tree

I'm using https://github.com/dotJEM/angular-tree as a recursive directive to loop through this kind of model :

```
  $scope.model = [
      {
          label: 'parent1',
          children: [{
              label: 'child'
          }]
      }, 
      {
          label: 'parent2',
          children: [{
              label: 'child',
              children: [{
                  label: 'innerChild'
              }]
          }]
      }, 
      {
          label: 'parent3'
      }
  ];
```

**In the template, the code looks like this:**

```
<div data-dx-start-with="model">
    <div data-ng-repeat="node in $dxPrior">
        <a class="list-group-item">
            <span class="icon" data-ng-click="toggle(node)"><i class=" icon ion-android-arrow-dropdown"></i>&nbsp;</span>
            <span>{{ node.label}} ({{node.children.length}})</span>
        </a>
        <ul data-ng-show="node.expanded" data-dx-connect="node.children"></ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, how would I go about accessing each parent? I want to be able to build a breadcrumb of the treeview.

**Ex :** parent2 > child > innerChild > ...

I can get each node's parent by using $parent if I'm not mistaken... but how would I go about getting each parent(s)?

I have created a plnkr to illustrate : http://plnkr.co/edit/DOc9k4jT9iysJLFvvg3u?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just program it. Make function that will walk thru parents until reach the root and construct array of parents in each step:

```
$scope.getParentsBreadcrumb = function (thisScope) {
  var parents = [];
  while (thisScope && thisScope.node) {
    parents.unshift (thisScope.node.label);
    thisScope = thisScope.$parent.$parent;
  }
  return parents.join(' > ')
}
```

Then call it in your template where you want to print breadcrumbs:

```
{{getParentsBreadcrumbs (this)}}
```

Comment: I don't think this is working properly : http://plnkr.co/edit/DOc9k4jT9iysJLFvvg3u?p=preview   :(

Comment: Ok, in your specific case, there are 2 steps for every level. So it needs to only skip over two parents instead one: ```thisScope = thisScope.$parent.$parent```. See http://plnkr.co/edit/9MNBrcIxXyGDpUZhxjZX?p=preview